# Refactoring front end code by minimizing dependancies

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, refactoring

Large web applications tend to accrue a huge array of libraries that support both front-end and back-end functionality. I want to reduce the number of dependencies in order to increase stability and ease of maintenance. I'm looking for a good path to reducing dependencies in a web app that includes libraries such as:

- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
- [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)/[Select2](https://select2.github.io/)
- [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) plus various plugins
- [d3](https://d3js.org/)/[Raphael](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/)
- [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)
- [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

I'm looking for techniques, languages, or frameworks that combine as many of those dependencies as possible.

Here's what I've explored so far:

**Refactoring** small dependencies and removing unused parts could go a long way.

**[React](https://facebook.github.io/react/)** would impose discipline on the jQuery spaghetti code and reduce the need for a few of the dependencies.

**[Elm](http://elm-lang.org/)** would go farther towards imposing discipline with its type safety.

**[ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript)** would also impose discipline through a functional programming paradigm.

Except for refactoring, all of these potential solutions would introduce some additional complexity of their own in order to integrate with the Ruby on Rails back-end. React seems to have the most replacements for the current dependencies.

The safest path forward seems to be to start with refactoring and gradually introduce one of the functional languages or libraries. How would I refactor with this goal in mind? Would first refactoring to plain JS (i.e. removing jQuery) be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Libraries/dependencies

Usually when I inherit a large project to refactor, the first thing to do is determine the core dependency e.g. what's the main library most of your custom code uses? From your list I can already tell **underscore** and **jQuery** are basically trying to do the same thing. Which one is the most optimized and fastest has been gradually leveled during the years. Let's assume for a second Underscore is still the fastest, you're still depending on jQuery for traversing and what not. Are you willing to include an extra library to gain micro speeds? The extra payload for each page is not worth it in my opinion.

Then **Bootstrap** is most likely your main CSS driver, however, it has some JavaScript abilities which might be used. Carousel, date-picker, drop-down, toggle some other widgets ... See if they are used (probably yes), if not, get rid of the Bootstrap js library. Keep in mind Bootstrap is still depending on jQuery.

**Chosen/select** are optional plugins. They're goal is most likely covered in Bootstrap/jQuery. Try to refactor them out.

**Slickgrid** is also a grid system. What's the benefit over the Bootstrap grid? Sounds like they refactored out Bootstrap. If it's used, refactor to a bootstrap grid to increase the common knowledge of the team.

**Handlebars** for templating. If you use the logic operators it's useful, otherwise you can easily find a small replacement function.

```
function renderTemplate(obj, template) {
    var tempKey, reg, key;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            tempKey = String("{{" + key + "}}");
            reg = new RegExp(tempKey, "g");
            template = template.replace(reg, obj[key]);
        }
    }

    return template;
}
```

**CKEditor/Raphael** are libraries with one specific goal in mind => wysiwyg/vector. Best to keep those but lazy loading sounds ideal. Only include them on the page when they are needed.

```
// after the additional library was loaded ...
cacheObj1.on('focus', this.initCKE);
cacheObj2.on('click', this.initVector);
```

If you're server language handles `<script>` includes into the `<head>` tag, you can choose to keep simple script references, required by the specific page in mind. Don't end up with twenty DOM ready events inline, try to end up with just one ready event to initialize everything your project needs.

1. jQuery plus various plugins
2. Bootstrap
3. Handlebars

   - <strike>CKEditor</strike> refactor to lazy loading
   - <strike>Chosen/Select2</strike> refactor to core lib
   - <strike>d3/Raphael</strike> refactor to lazy loading
   - <strike>SlickGrid</strike> refactor to core lib
   - <strike>Underscore</strike> refactor to core lib

## Application/custom JS

Now the tricky part begins. How good are your JavaScript skills and how decent was the previous programmer? If you find a lot of jQuery selectors all over the place, chances are high it's not programmed in a modular approach. The hard task of refactoring every peace of code to something configurable begins.

The idea here is to have an instance or loader file which talks to your libraries. Perhaps a custom function file (which can hold underscore functions if you prefer) to use throughout your code. Prototypes or "classes" and singletons to finish it off. A [nice post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77843/order-a-delicious-pie-here/78333#78333) about refactoring if I may add with links on how to set this up. Then a grunt/gulp setup is nothing too fancy these days. Automation for JS(npm, bower) and CSS(compass, less) can be covered on the fly.

## Conclusion

jQuery is most likely your main dependency. So you will start from scratch if you take it out. All the plugins you talk about is the extra fat on page load. The less the better, but sometimes it pays off just to RE-USE other functionalities like cookie scripts, json support, polyfills, ... the list goes on and on. Try to stick with one or two core libraries and clearly separate dependencies and application code.

Don't forget to [bundle and minify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022556/javascript-confusing-with-script-file-placing-place/39023042#39023042) ^^

Happy refactoring!

Comment: This helps a lot! What do you mean by lazy loading? I assume just loading on pages that need it, but Rails' asset pipeline makes that tricky. Do you mean use a CDN?
Each of those dependencies was chosen for a reason, like SlickGrid because it can merge columns. So using a core lib will mean re-implementing some functionality. Not sure if it's worth the effort in some cases.

Comment: So you need to think about the sequence of library loading, as I numbered up. In between 1 and 2 you can add several jQuery plugins as they hook up into the `$` object. `Modernizr` is something I would put on 0 by example. You bundle and minify it, and everything extra, that is only used in specific occassions got included dynamically, either by placing script tags in the head, or by ajax library loading or other techniques.